# django better way to write model field choices?

Tags: django, class, model, field

I have a model class with some "status" fields, which have a `choices` option (each choice have its own business logic).
According to the Django website, this is how choices should be set:

```
class Order:
   STATUS_ACTIVE = 1
   STATUS_ENDED = 2
   STATUS_CANCELED = 3
   ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = ( (STATUS_ACTIVE, 'Active'),
                             (STATUS_ENDED, 'Ended'),
                             (STATUS_CANCELED, 'Canceled'), )

   order_status = models.IntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES)
   order_status2 = models.IntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUS2_CHOICES)
```

The problem is, it's feels bad to spam my model class with many choices for many fields, it it possible to encapsulate it somehow, but still to keep these choices **inside** the model class ?

I've tried using an inner class like

```
class OrderStatus:
       STATUS_ACTIVE = 1
       STATUS_ENDED = 2
```

But referring to Order.OrderStatus.STATUS_ACTIVE from inside the model class raises an error.

Comment: Why do you want to keep it inside model?

Comment: cause these choices relate to the model fields? Also according to django website, it best to put choices inside the class.. though if I see they become big I might separate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate those choices in a `dict`:

```
   status1 = {'STATUS_ACTIVE': 1,
   'STATUS_ENDED': 2,
   'STATUS_CANCELED': 3, 
   'ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES': ( (STATUS_ACTIVE, 'Active'),
                             (STATUS_ENDED, 'Ended'),
                             (STATUS_CANCELED, 'Canceled'), )}


   order_status = models.IntegerField(choices=status1['ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES'])
   order_status2 = models.IntegerField(choices=status2['ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES'])
```

Comment: This is nice, give me an idea

Comment: That's just what I did here imo.

Answer (score 1):

If django doc tells you to do so, it's not a spam, it's how people use them. You could do something similar with less code:

```
STATUS_ACTIVE, STATUS_ENDED, STATUS_CANCELED = range(1, 4)
```

Comment: It become larger when you have many status fields, also you cant use the same names again, so choice enum-name like ACTIVE which appear in choices of two model fields, you cant use it again. So I try to encapsulate it somehow

Answer (score 0):

What will change if you use this instead?

`ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Active'),
    (2, 'Ended'),
    (3, 'Canceled')
)`

Or this ?

`ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('1', '1-Active'),
    ('2', '2-Ended'),
    ('3', '3-Canceled')
)`

Comment: That when doing logic I will have to compare to '1', instead of some enum type.. today I can do instance.status == Order.ACTIVE, clearer code